# Running iconized application unreachable?

Tags: windows

Some applications like Privoxy start iconized, and sometimes, the app is running but is no longer displayed in the icon bar (XP).

Task Manager only includes an "End Process" button, but no "Bring to screen" button.

Does someone know of a way to somehow recover the UI of a running application?

Answer (score 0):

One app that I use has the option to hide the icon.  When it is set that way, the only way to bring it back up is to relaunch the program.  Whether your program will work that way or not depends on if it is set to allow additional instances or not.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. The app doesn't like it and ends up with "Fatal error: can't bind to 127.0.0.1:1234: There may be another app or some other proxy running on port 1234". I'll go ask the developers.